# Acceptance test for a flow that uses the transient package?

Tags: transient-library, with-simulated-input

I am trying to write a test around a flow that uses transient. Here is the sample code:

```
;; -*- lexical-binding: t; coding: utf-8 -*-

(require 'transient)
(require 'buttercup)
(require 'with-simulated-input)

(defun ogt-print-a () (interactive) (insert "a"))
(defun ogt-print-b () (interactive) (insert "b"))

(transient-define-prefix ogt-transient ()
  ["X"
   ("f" "test f" ogt-print-a)
   ("g" "test g" ogt-print-b)])

(describe
 "Transient"
 (it "takes keys"
     (with-temp-buffer
       (with-simulated-input "f"
         (ogt-transient)
         (expect (buffer-string)
                 :to-match "a")))))
```

Now, I would expect the library "with-simulated-input" to press "f" when the transient comes up and to have that put "a" in the temp buffer, as that's what the function called should do.

However, it does not add anything, and the temp buffer remains empty.

I could use some help, I really would like to *know for a fact* that my package works.

I wondered if `with-temp-buffer` could be the culprit but changing this to a `set-buffer` call did not seem to help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Author of with-simulated-input here. This happens because `with-simulated-input` is expecting BODY to read input, and `ogt-transient` doesn't read input. It only sets up the appropriate key bindings to implement the transient menu and then returns, letting Emacs handle those key bindings as normal. However, when it returns, `with-simulated-input` assumes it is "done" and continues evaluating BODY. In this case, since `ogt-transient` sets up the appropriate bindings and returns without blocking on input, you don't actually need `with-simulated-input` at all. You can simply follow it by the appropriate `execute-kbd-macro` form, e.g.

```
(progn 
  (ogt-transient)
  (execute-kbd-macro "f"))
```

For more details, see the issue [here](https://github.com/DarwinAwardWinner/with-simulated-input/issues/16).